# Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'data' of defined

Tags: javascript, android, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

Trying to populate a list of feeds from an application generated in sencha cmd. The feeds are stored in a store, and I can edit which ones are visible. Upon trying to open one of said feeds I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

at this line

> if (a.data.feeds.length == 1 && a.data.feeds[0].format == "html") {
>                 mobEdu.util.loadExternalUrl(a.data.feeds[0].link)           }

I'm open to any and all suggestions. Let me know if I can clarify any further thank you!

```
Ext.define("mobEdu.feeds.f", {
    statics: {
        curParentID: null,
        curModuleID: null,
        curModuleCode: null,
        curFeedID: null,
        editMode: false,
        moduleTitle: null,
        feedTitle: null,
        feedsTitles: null,
        navStack: new Array(),
        loadFeeds: function(b) {
            if (b === undefined || b === null) {
                b = mobEdu.util.loginModuleCode
            }
            var d = mobEdu.util.getModuleId(b);
            mobEdu.feeds.f.curModuleID = d;
            mobEdu.feeds.f.curModuleCode = b;
            mobEdu.feeds.f.editMode = false;
            mobEdu.util.get("mobEdu.feeds.view.list");
            var c = mobEdu.util.getStore("mobEdu.feeds.store.feedsMenus");
            var a;
            c.each(function(e) {
                if (e.data.moduleId === d) {
                    a = e
                }
            });
            c.getServerProxy().setExtraParams({
                clientCode: campusCode,
                companyID: companyId,
                page: 0
            });
            if (a.data.feeds.length == 1 && a.data.feeds[0].format == "html") {
                mobEdu.util.loadExternalUrl(a.data.feeds[0].link)
            } else {
                if (a.data.feeds.length == 1 && a.data.feeds[0].format == "CAS") {
                    mobEdu.util.openURLWithCAS(a.data.feeds[0].link)
                } else {
                    this.navStack = [];
                    mobEdu.feeds.f.loadFeedList(a)
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: if `e.data.moduleId === d` always fails, `a` is never defined.

Comment: can't find where e is set

Comment: It's set in the arguments of the function passed to `each`. You've no clue what your code is doing???

Comment: This is inherited code from an offshore development team. That is no longer with us having to black box it for the time being